# Error connecting to gov.uk WFS in QGIS 2.18.15

Tags: qgis, wfs

I am trying to connect to a UK Government WFS but am getting the following error:

Layer minerals_local_plan: Download of features for layer inspire_inspire_energy:minerals_local_plan failed or partially failed: Download of features failed: Error downloading http://map.cornwall.gov.uk/arcgis/services/inspire/inspire_energy/MapServer/WFSServer?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=inspire_inspir

Below is the URL for the WFS:
http://map.cornwall.gov.uk/arcgis/services/inspire/inspire_energy/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS

I am not sure where I am going wrong The URL is correct and QGIS seems to be connecting to the server, as layers within the WFS are identified in the Browser Panel.

Comment: Did you cut the url when you wrote your question, or did QGIS do that? This at least returns data http://map.cornwall.gov.uk/arcgis/services/inspire/inspire_energy/MapServer/WFSServer?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=inspire_inspire_energy:minerals_local_plan

Comment: Misnamed INSPIRE if only supports EPSG:27700. INSPIRE requires a CRS that uses ETRS:89 and EPSG:27700 does not.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the server doesn't understand the bounding box that QGIS is sending (If you look at the log it shows you the URL being tried).

```
BBOX=99339.43836907130025793,13627.98741020512534305,278372.96811008598888293,123754.28037196293007582,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700
```

Trying the URL from the log in a browser gives

```
<ExceptionReport version="2.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">
 <Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="Unknown">
  <ExceptionText>KVP parser : parameter 'bbox' '-483667.18412089953199029,13627.98741020512534305,861379.59060005680657923,123754.28037196293007582,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700' not recognized.
   </ExceptionText>
 </Exception>
</ExceptionReport>
```

If you try it again with out the fith parameter (the SRSname) it works. I'm pretty sure that is a server bug, so I'd suggest contacting the supplier except they haven't filled in the relevant information.

Comment: feedback can be done via https://secure.cornwall.gov.uk/selfservice/citizenportal/form.aspx?form=Feedback&tmpl=Feedback @GeorgeF